# Ubuntu - Install cassandra version 3.0.9 fails: Version '3.0.9' for 'cassandra' was not found

Tags: ubuntu, apt, cassandra

I have ansible scripts that were used to provision some cassandra servers a couple months ago.

They are failing now on this command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-193:~$ sudo apt-get install cassandra=3.0.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.0.9' for 'cassandra' was not found
```

It seems this version was removed from the repository. How can I get this working again?

Thanks,
Drew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the `http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 30x main` repo there is only a 3.0.12 package in it. I would recommend that for what its worth. 3.0.9 had some pretty bad bugs including data loss ones. The deb is available at http://dl.bintray.com/apache/cassandra/pool/main/c/cassandra/cassandra-tools_3.0.9_all.deb if you want to get it though.